# Lotus Domino and user status (logged in/out)

Tags: lotus-domino

Is there any way to check if user is logged in to the Lotus Domino from third party website without SSO?

I have got that response from Domino admin:

> You send us a request and we simply return to you a text string.
>   Within the string will be login status and welcome message.

but in that case it comes to my mind SSO (as request) from "my" wesbite to their Domino, but I'm not 100% sure about it - maybe he is right.

Comment: Not without writing you're own code. It would be relatively straightforward. But effectively you would just be simulating SSO in your own proprietary way. I'm assuming you want to determine programmatically, if someone is logged in. Administrators can determine it but it requires looking at the domlog.nsf.

Comment: It looks like the image is not be present on your sever or your mail server doesn't have access to the file location. The html could do with a tidy by closing the font tag and the image having a closing / just in case it has spat the dummy